# Azure Cloud Service Performance

Tags: c#, performance, azure, pdf, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure Cloud Service that hosts a website that generates PDF files. The PDF files can vary in size up to around 10MB. Its a .NET MVC Entity Framework site that uses PDFSharp/Migradoc to generate the PDFs.

I've been trying to improve the performance of the PDF generation and I've found that even when increasing the instance size - for example from A2 to A4 - I see little change in performance.

I checked the monitor in the portal and it doesn't show a very high usage, and I also checked the Resource Monitor on one of the Cloud Service servers and the memory usage was at most 50% usage.

Azure Portal Monitor:

[image: Azure Portal Monitor]

Resource Monitor:

[image: Resource Monitor]

Note: the memory usage is at 50%, CPU usage is low and most of the network usage displayed seems to be from the remote desktop connection.

I imagine the slowness is either due to slow disc write speed or long garbage collection intervals but I'm not sure how to prove this.

I'd greatly appreciate any pointers or ideas that can help me to improve the performance. I can also upgrade the instance size to one of the newer instances (D/D2 series) if you think a faster SD drive or CPU will help, but since the CPU usage is so low I'm not sure if that would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a programming related question buried in here somewhere?

Comment: Well, my question is regarding performance in the Cloud - looking at the displayed metrics what could cause the code to be running slow even when the CPU and memory allocated are increased. When the CPU and memory usage is low what are the remaining bottlenecks that could be slowing down the PDF code? Is it possible that there are gaps of garbage collection that are halting the program or could it be that the disc write or network out speed are too slow. I think its fair to say that these are all programming related issues since no code runs in isolation of its environment.

Comment: true, but its not something we can replicate, and is somewhat offtopic for stack overflow. You might have better luck on superuser

Comment: @Takarii Definitely not on SuperUser. This is about profiling the solution - it's either for SO or maybe for SF.

Comment: @joechip What's the exact problem? Is that PDF processing running slower when you increase the number of requests? Do you see intensive disk IO? Do you observe better performance on your dev computer?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I found that the larger A sized instances, whilst containing more CPU cores, are not faster per core. This meant I was not seeing the expected improvements. The actual load is very heavy in terms of RAM and CPU as more PDFs are generated. I will look into upgrading to one of the newer D sized instances instead.